# How can I recover firefox bookmarks and passwords from HD from broken laptop?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, windows-vista, passwords, bookmarks

My laptop died (running on Vista).  I have removed it's HDD, put it in a caddy and have got all my files.  But I would like to access my passwords and if possible my bookmarks from Mozilla Firefox?

I am now using an HP with Windows 7.

What would happen if I swapped over the hard drives?  Would it fire up my old laptop environment and would it damage the bios settings on the new machine? 
Then I could access my passwords & Bookmarks?

Comment: If you have access to the data on the hdd.  You just copy the Firefox profile.  If you don't then you don't have access to the data and you won't be able to recover the data.

Answer (score 1):

When using Linux (ahhhh! ;) you could swap a harddisk like that, if the processor type is compatible. With Windows you could try, but I think it won't work unless the laptop is of the same type.

Much easier

- copy the Mozilla profile and zip it as a backup
- shutdown firefox
- move your new profile to the desktop
- move the old profile into the Profiles folder
- try and see if that works

Location:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile>\
```

If this doesn't work, you can put back the original folder of the current installation, and then replace the contents of the folders.

Comment: And if he doesn't use firefox?

Comment: Please read the question. He mentions Firefox!

Comment: Ahh, I fail reading at comprehension today apparently...

Comment: Why would the processor type be important?  I have copied the profile from a system with a processor released 6 years before to a system that uses the Haswell Core i7 processor I now use.

Comment: @Ramhound He is talking about booting up the hard disk in another computer.

Comment: What prevents him from booting with entirely different hardware is not the processor though its other devices which is easily solved but outside of the scope of trying to copy the Firefox profile on the hdd.  External Enclosure would be easier and be platform independent.